# How to repeat action with query, in case of authentication issues?

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuex, nuxt.js

I have get menu action with authentication.

```
  async getMenu({rootState, commit}) {
    try {
      const { auth, lang } = rootState;

      const {items} = await this.$axios.$get(`/api/${ lang.locale }/menu`, {
        headers: {
          'Authorization': `bearer ${auth.token}`,
          'Accept-Language': `${lang.locale}`
        },
      });

      if (items) {
        // set items
        commit('setMenu', items);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log({Error: error})
    }
  }
```

In case of error, I submit request with refresh token

```
  $axios.onError(async (error) => {
    const code = parseInt(error.response && error.response.status);
    const message = error.response && error.response.data && error.response.data.error;

      if (code === 403) {
        await store.dispatch(
          'auth/refreshToken',
          { refreshToken: store.state.auth.refreshToken },
          { root: true }
        );
```

How to repeat action after get token ?

Comment: How about using [Axios interceptor](https://github.com/axios/axios#interceptors)? the idea is that Axios would intercept an error such as "Token is expired". On this specific condition, Axios should provide you the information used for the failed request through `error.config`. You just update the token and resend it

Comment: @Al-un How to return resut to initial action ?

Comment: What do you mean by `resu(l)t to initial action`? If your token is expired, your request should fall in error such as `503: not authorized`

Comment: @Al-un I have to refresh token.

Comment: @Al-un and redirect to page

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
  $axios.defaults.validateStatus = (status) => {
    return [200, 402].indexOf(status) !== -1;
  };

  $axios.onResponse(async (response) => {...}
```